# How do i connect my .cs class with my .aspx class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to call my funktions in my .cs class over in my .aspx class, it looks like it finds my class, but gives me a "Server error in application '/'" when i run the application. It says it's my public partial class Create_b_code is the problem.

I have tryed to add reference System.Web.dll, but it seems to not do anything.  I have also tryed to add : System.Web.UI.Page after but it can seem to find the "UI" part and i cant get to install it.

This is my .cs class my fucnktion creates a txt file and it works if I just run this class.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.IO;

public partial class Create_b_code
{
  public static void Create_new_file(string LTOname)
    {
        string path = @"C:\test\logfile_timeout_" + LTOname +".txt";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("  ");                
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This is my .aspx class, all works if i dont call the <%@ page.... %> part.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Create_b_code.cs"
    Inherits="Create_b_code" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

This is were I use a button to call my fucntion from .cs

```
<button runat="server" id="btnSubmit"  class="btn btn-submit" text="Submit"
    onclick="Create_new_file()">Submit</button>
```

So if I dont call the "<%@ page.... %>" in my .aspx i can see everything but ofc my submit function is not working, but when i have "<%@ page.... %>" in my class to make the connection I get this.
This is from my web-browser were i run the lochalhost application:

```
Server error in application '/'.
Compile
Description: An error occurred while compiling a resource required to process this
request. Read the following details about the error and make the necessary changes
to the source code.
Compilation function error message: ASPNET: Verify that the class defined in this 
code file matches the 'inherits' attribute and extends the correct base class (for 
example, Page or UserControl).
Source Error:
Linje 7:  public partial class Create_b_code
```

Comment: as th error says: `public partial class Create_b_code : Page or UserControl`

Comment: When i use "public partial class Create_b_code : Page or Usercontrol" it import the reference System.Web.dll and use "using System.Web.UI" but i get a error that it's not available for my project. I could greate a new project that supports reference, but don't know which ones dose

Comment: What's the full name of the code file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .cs file:

```
public partial class Create_b_code : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: I have tryed typing this after the class name, but it says " CS0234 C# The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" i tryed adding the reference "System.Web.dll" but it dosen't work, i don't know if it's the wrong reference or what. I have 
search a lot and all says it's that one.

Comment: could it be the project there dosent support references? i have tryed makeing 2 different projects with the same code. one as "Windows App (.NET Fameowrk)" and one as Windows Froms app (.NET Core)?

Comment: In Visual Studio, choose File > New Project. On the left, expand Visual C#, select Web, and then select ASP.NET Web Forms Application.

Answer (score 0):

Note the name of the code file you listed:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Create_b_code.cs"
Inherits="Create_b_code" %>
```

The code-behind file should be `Create_b_code.aspx.cs`. Note the **.aspx**.

So your `Page` directive should be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Create_b_code.aspx.cs"
Inherits="Create_b_code" %>
```

Make sure that that actually *is* the name of the code-behind file.

You can have separate, stand-alone code files, but that works differently than web-form + code-behind files.

Comment: Also add ` : System.Web.UI.Page` as mentioned in Roman K's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it now works after following you and Roman K.

Comment: i can't. When i upvote it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."